# Adicionar array ao final de outro array em um foreach

Tags: php, php-7

```
$celulas = array (

  0 => array ("idCelula" => 17,"nomeCelula" => "Célula 1" ),
  1 => array ("idCelula" => 18,"nomeCelula" => "Célula 2" )

);

foreach ( $celulas as $celula ) {

        $celulasPesquisa = null;

        $celulasReunioes = array (

          0 => array ("idCelula" => 17,"diaReuniao" => 5)

        );
        array_push ( $celula, $celulasReunioes );
}

print_r($celulas);
```

Meu **objetivo** é que para **cada** `$celula` do **array** `$celulas` seja *acrescentado* um **array** `$celulasReunioes` que traz as **reuniões** daquela **célula**.

Ou seja que o `array` ***final*** `$celulas` fique assim:

```
$celulas = array (

  0 => array (
               "idCelula" => 17,
                "nomeCelula" => "Célula 1", 
                array ( 0 => array ("idCelula" => 17,"diaReuniao" => 5)

  1 => array (
               "idCelula" => 18,
                "nomeCelula" => "Célula 2", 
                array ( 0 => array ("idCelula" => 18,"diaReuniao" => 12)

);
```

O que é preciso fazer?

Pois do jeito que estou fazendo não está dando certo!

Detalhe, tentei criar um exemplo mínimo conforme orientação.

Da forma que está,

```
print_ ( $celulas );
```

**imprime**:

```
$celulas = array (

  0 => array ("idCelula" => 17,"nomeCelula" => "Célula 1" ),
  1 => array ("idCelula" => 18,"nomeCelula" => "Célula 2" )

);
```

Ou seja, sem a adição do `foreach`

Comment: Cara, que bagunça! O seu objetivo **final** está bem **des**estruturado...

Comment: tá mesmo, kkk, mas já estou dando um jeito nessa bagunça... valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você precisa alterar o elemento do *array*, precisa manter a **referência** do mesmo. Lembre-se que o `foreach` itera naturalmente sobre uma cópia do *array*.

Assim, precisa colocar o caractere `&` indicando a referência:

```
foreach ($celulas as &$celula) {

}
```

Fazendo isso terá o resultado desejado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idCelula] => 17
            [nomeCelula] => Célula 1
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [idCelula] => 17
                            [diaReuniao] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idCelula] => 18
            [nomeCelula] => Célula 2
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [idCelula] => 17
                            [diaReuniao] => 5
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Mas sinto na obrigação de comentar que não faz muito sentido ter um *array* associativo com índices numéricos. Faria muito mais sentido nesse caso os dados ficarem no índice `"reunioes"` ou algo equivalente.

Comment: que estranho, criou o incide mas não trouxe o valor do array adicionado. trouxe vazio.

Comment: Então fez alguma coisa errada, pois pegando o seu código e somente adicionando o `&` já devia funcionar: https://repl.it/@acwoss/SevereDistortedDrupal.

Comment: @CarlosRocha cara, tenho percebido que vc tá com bastante dificuldade em reproduzir os códigos das respostas aqui do site. Qual versão do PHP você está utilizando?! Naquela outra pergunta que formulei uma resposta você tb não conseguiu reproduzir. Aliás, eu tentei GERAR o seu problema e não consegui... Tem algo BEEEM errado aí! De repente você tá rodando um PHP 1.0 e não sabe.(kkk) Acaba sendo difícil reproduzir os códigos...

Comment: tem sim irmão, o objetivo era xriar como o outro colega falou mais um índice chamado "reunioes" e popular ele com o resultado da query que busca as reuniões no banco, ou seja, $celula ["renunioes"] = array()

Comment: dí tentei fazer array_push ( $celula["reunioes"], $celulasReunioes ); sai de novo vazio. Cria o ínidce, mas com valor vazio. Se vai o indice numérico sai o valor

Comment: Coloque no repl.it o seu exemplo funcionando e nos envie o link. Só na especulação do que você fez errado não teremos como ajudar.

Comment: feito, https://repl.it/@CarlosRocha1/WorthwhileSillySolidstatedrive?language=php&folderId=

Comment: @CarlosRocha Parece estar funcionando normalmente, onde está o problema?

Comment: não consigo substituir o índice [0] que está junto aos ínidces com palavras, mudar para "reunioes" sem que se acrecente mais ítens ao array reunioes

Comment: ou seja, gostaria que fossem, [idCelula], [nomeCelula], [reunioes] ao invés de [idCelula], [nomeCelula], [0]

Comment: Mas na pergunta você solicitou que o índice fosse numérico, não "reunioes". Está ficando cada vez mais confusa a sua pergunta...

Comment: sim, perdão, foi o recurso que tive a principio uma vez que não estava conseguindo, pensei assim, se consigo com números com letras tb conseguirei.. Mais vez: desculpas pela falha

Comment: apenas tentei fazer uma pergunta o mais enxuta possível e nessa tentativa acabei retiando um foreach. Bastou aqui no sistema adicionar o coringa & aos 2 foreach que deu certo. Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei o `&$celula` para que ele realmente altere o array passando ele por referência e imprima o resultado abaixo, que é o que você quer:

```
<?php

$celulas = array(
    0 => array("idCelula" => 17, "nomeCelula" => "Célula 1"),
    1 => array("idCelula" => 18, "nomeCelula" => "Célula 2")
);

$org_celula = array();

$org_celula[] = [
    'idCelula' => 17,
    'diaReuniao' => 5
];

$org_celula[] = [
    'idCelula' => 18,
    'diaReuniao' => 12
];

foreach ($celulas as $index => &$celula) {
    foreach ($org_celula as $key => $cell) {

        if ($key === $index) {
            $celula['celula'] = $cell;
        }
    }
}

print_r($celulas);
```